# HSTS header in .htaccess set up, but not working

Tags: .htaccess, security, https, header, hsts

I set the lines below on .htaccess file for many websites I developed :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

<if "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</if>
```

I also successfully added the concerned domains on https://hstspreload.org/

Unfortunately, all tests I've done (Chrome development tools, https://securityheaders.com) in order to check if HSTS was well operational failed.

All of the domains have a valid SSL certificate installed, for all domains and subdomains.
I also tried to set headers with PHP, same results.

Does anyone know why, and how to make HSTS effective to pass the test ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "failed" exactly? How did you "successfully" submit the domains to `hstspreload.org` when your tests result in "failure"? What version of Apache are you using? What HTTP response headers are you seeing for your various test requests?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
About "failure" I mean that all tests made on different tools (Checkbot add-on on Chrome, domain checkings on securityheaders.com, ...) indicate HSTS is not detected on the domain despite my .htaccess.

By "successfully" for hstspreload.org I mean that I entered the domain to check HSTS preload and eligibility, and it was successful (background page on green, and availibility of sending button to add the domain to the preload list).

Comment: I don't know how to get the Apache version. I tried with SSH access, and all commands are not found (httpd, apache2, apache2ctl). I tried with phpinfo(), only "Apache" is indicated. I tried by checking headers on Chrome, and the same : only "Apache" is written.